# How do I tell which module a function comes from?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to read the help on what various things do as I'm reading through code. I'm getting a bit lost in how to determine which module a function comes from. Here is my current example:

```
import quandl
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
amzn = quandl.get("WIKI/AMZN", start_date="2018-01-01", end_date="2019-01-01")
amzn_daily_close = amzn[['Adj. Close']]
amzn_daily_log_returns = np.log(amzn_daily_close.pct_change()+1)
monthly = amzn.resample('BM').apply(lambda x: x[-1])
```

So given this block of code, I can do help (quandl.get) to see information about that and help (np.log) to see what that does. But when I get to amzn.resample, where is that resample coming from? What should I be entering to see some help information on the resample stuff?

Comment: I'm using jupyter notebook... If I type monthly = amzn.res and tab I can choose resample. Where in this set of keystrokes would I be doing the cntrl+q?

Comment: Try `?` and `??` after a variable or member.

Comment: A note for the future -- we're a knowledgebase, not a forum. A question should be as focused as possible on content that's applicable to everyone else with the same problem (so others with the same issue can find existing questions on the same topic and learn from their answers); self-deprecation isn't really necessary towards that end.

Comment: ...moving back towards topic -- unfortunately, introspection mechanisms aren't 100% reliable across the different ways objects in Python can be defined. Instances will have a `__class__` associated, classes will have a `__module__`, modules will have a `__file__`, but C-defined types can be very inconsistent depending on how they're implemented, so those generalities aren't 100% guaranteed to be true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, these modules should be documented somewhere. They are usually "packaged" and made available on [Python Package Index](https://pypi.org/) (pypi). You can search there for your package name and find the [quandl page](https://pypi.org/project/Quandl/). That may have a link to the projects home page with [more documentation](https://github.com/quandl/quandl-python).

Answer (score 1):

### Inspection

You can 'inspect' the method to find the implementation:

```
import inspect

print(inspect.getfile(amzn.resample))

# /opt/miniconda/envs/stackoverflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py
```

### IDE

Or you can use a good IDE (e.g. [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm) or IntelliJ) which supports you with some neat features:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you! It looks like I need more of an IDE than just the notebook. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

**Look at the docstring of quandl.get method** to get the help message about the  return  object. This will contain a statement as `returns x-object`. Googling about `x-object` will give you more info on this.

Alternatively, you can do this. To identify what is the object you can do the below.

```
amzn_type = type(amzn)
```

This gives the monthly object type. Googling for this type value will give you more insights about that object.Example -

```
a = 10
print(type(a))
```

The above code returns `<class 'int'>` output. Googling about `int` class in python3 will be helpful.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'm not so much interested in the type of the data as much as where "resample" comes from and how to get help on it.

Comment: Updated the appropriate section of  the answer.